# Getting assertion error while performing test on mockmvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing

I am getting assertion error saying it's getting `406` and expected `200`. Not sure how to fix this. For your info i am trying to upgrade spring boot 1.5.2 to 2.1.4

Below is my code -

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ChangeController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ChangeControllerTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();

        }

         @Test
        public void verifyInvalidToDoArgument() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/log").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(print());
        }


}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/log")
public class ChangeController {
    @ApiIgnore

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"text/plain"})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String generate() {

        return "some string is here
               ";

    }
}
```

Below is console response-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :406
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant part of the controller class ?

Comment: @Arnaud i have added controller class

Comment: Your controller produces "text/plain" but your request accepts "application/json".

Comment: okay i have changed this line -  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/log").contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)) and it worked